# Where can I find an iPhone chart library?

Tags: iphone, charts

I'm looking for a good charting library in Objective-C and iOS compliant (iPad mostly).

I've a requirement to display rich bar-charts (touch-flyouts to indicate the values on x and y axis), pie-charts, line graph etc.

I've explored sm2dgraphview and Core Plot and it appears they are not complete.

If there are any good commercial libraries out there, I would be happy to explore them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS chart libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724887/ios-chart-libraries)

Comment: What, exactly, is Core Plot missing for your application?  It has styled bar charts, pie charts, and line graphs.  It's also highly extensible, although it may not be the easiest framework to get set up.

Comment: User interactions on the bars is the first thing that I find missing.

Comment: That capability was added on July 30, 2010, so it's been in the framework for a while: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=174 .  Simply implement the `-barPlot:barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:` delegate method to be informed of touch events on your bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Eiko's link I found [threedgraphics](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/ioschart/) as a nice interface for charting.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html) in a UIWebView.

Comment: I'm looking for Obj-C library for charting, that would be bespoke and provides user interaction. Not very keen on using Webview.

Answer (score 0):

CorePlot  is a very good library for the ios and mac as well you can download from this location:
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/list